# Como hacer un selector de Color

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

quiero hacer un selector de colores como el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hice el div, y en el background le mando un linear-gradient

```
.bg{
    width: 15px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    //left: 0;
    right: 30px;
    //bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, red 0%, #ff0 17%, lime 33%, cyan 50%, blue 66%, #f0f 83%, red 100%);
}
```

y tambien logro arrastrar el puntero por medio de click.

La pregunta es Como obtengo el color en que me encuentro?

O existe una formula para calcular el gradiente con la posicion del puntero?

Comment: Hola Raul, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo leer [ask], hacer el [tour] (y ganar así tu primera medalla) y aprender a hacer un [mcve]. Tal y como tienes la pregunta podría ser cerrada por demasiado amplia. ¿Cuál es tu HTML? ¿Quieres hacerlo todo tú o te valdría con plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te paso un enlace de MDN ya desarrollado:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Herramienta_para_seleccionar_color

espero que te sirva de referencia.

Comment: Gracias busque antes de preguntar pero no di con una solución, es muy bueno el enlace, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No me deja poner comentarios aún, la reputación de los novatos :P pero como te voy a agregar algo de código y una respuesta factible, lo pongo como respuestas.

Para montar lo que quieres debes recuperar el valor del input. Suponiendo que tengas(estaría genial que nos pusieras todo el código relacionado para no tener que hacer deducciones los demás):

```
<form method="post" action="miproceso.php">
    <input type="text" name="hexa">
    <input type="color" name="colorp">
</form>
```

Excluyo los inputs del rgb porque los veo mas bien decorativos, con el hexadecimal ya te valdría.

Necesitarías recoger el valor del input con name hexa. Te lo pongo en jQuery, que me parece una sintaxis mas limpia y rápida.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        var hexa=$('input[name:hexa]').val();
        alert(hexa);
    })
</script>
```

Esto te mostrará el valor hexadecimal en un mensaje de alerta, cambia el alert por lo que tu necesites para procesarlo.

Avisa si no te sirve y le damos una vuelta.